# Calculate the expectation of random differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a differential equation
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=F(g(x(t),\omega)),\;\;x_0=x,$$
where $\omega$ is standard normal variable.
Given that for each fixed $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\mathbb{E}_\omega[g(y,\omega)]=h(y),$$
here $h$ is a known function. Can we say anything about $\mathbb{E}_\omega[g(x(t),\omega)]$?

Here the things that boarders me is $x(t)$ is depends on $\omega.$ Thank you very much in advance.